# Elasticsearch get sum of values from a field based on another field

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch i'm trying to get the sum of values from a field based on another field.

I have the following data:

```json
{
    "id": "012345",
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 0101010,
            "subtotal": 15.55,
            "vat_percentage": 9.0,
            "vat": 1.4
        },
        {
            "id": 0101011,
            "subtotal": 17.0,
            "vat_percentage": 9.0,
            "vat": 1.53
        },
        {
            "id": 0101012,
            "subtotal": 12.98,
            "vat_percentage": 12.0,
            "vat": 1.56
        }
    ]
},
{
    ...
}
```

What I want is to get the **sum** of the `vat` values based on the `vat_percentage`, like this:

```
[
    {
        "vat_percentage": "9.0",
        "vat_sum": 2.93
    },
    {
        "vat_percentage": "12.0",
        "vat_sum": 1.56
    }
]
```

#### What I have tried

I have tried to make a `value_count` aggregation but it returns either an incorrect value or a `null` value:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "vat_count": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "admin_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also I tried to use nested queries and aggregations but could not wrap my head around it. This is what I tried:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "total_vat": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "rows",
        "query": {
          "term": {
            "rows.vat": "9.0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This throws the following error: `Unexpected token START_OBJECT in [total_vat]`.

How can I achieve this? I have very little experience with Elasticsearch so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the combination of [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html), [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) and [sum](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) aggregation.

Try using this query:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "total_vat": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "rows"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "unique_percentage": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "rows.vat_percentage"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "sum_count": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "rows.vat"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns with a `doc_count` of 286 but `doc_count_error_upper_bound` and `sum_other_doc_count` are 0. Also the `buckets` array is empty.

Comment: @Samball can you share your index mapping ?

Comment: No sorry my mistake made a typo, it works thank you!